# How are tools passed to llm? (final prompt sent to openai chat model)

Tags: nlp, openai-api, langchain

When using the openai chat api, we send an array of messages and tools. How are they assembled into a single prompt?

```
System:
Tools:
User:
Assistant:
User:
```

I tried setting `langchain.debug = True`, but I don't see the tools being passed to the llm.

```py
from langchain import hub
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor, create_openai_tools_agent
from langchain_community.tools.tavily_search import TavilySearchResults
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI

import langchain
langchain.debug = True

prompt = hub.pull("hwchase17/openai-tools-agent")
tools = [TavilySearchResults(max_results=1)]

llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106", temperature=0)
agent = create_openai_tools_agent(llm, tools, prompt)

agent_executor = AgentExecutor(agent=agent, tools=tools)

agent_executor.invoke({"input": "what is LangChain?"})
```

```
[chain/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor] Entering Chain run with input:
{
  "input": "what is LangChain?"
}
[chain/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 2:chain:RunnableSequence] Entering Chain run with input:
{
  "input": ""
}
[chain/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 2:chain:RunnableSequence > 3:chain:RunnableAssign<agent_scratchpad>] Entering Chain run with input:
{
  "input": ""
}
[chain/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 2:chain:RunnableSequence > 3:chain:RunnableAssign<agent_scratchpad> > 4:chain:RunnableParallel<agent_scratchpad>] Entering Chain run with input:
{
  "input": ""
}
[chain/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 2:chain:RunnableSequence > 3:chain:RunnableAssign<agent_scratchpad> > 4:chain:RunnableParallel<agent_scratchpad> > 5:chain:RunnableLambda] Entering Chain run with input:
{
  "input": ""
}
[chain/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 2:chain:RunnableSequence > 3:chain:RunnableAssign<agent_scratchpad> > 4:chain:RunnableParallel<agent_scratchpad> > 5:chain:RunnableLambda] [1ms] Exiting Chain run with output:
{
  "output": []
}
[chain/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 2:chain:RunnableSequence > 3:chain:RunnableAssign<agent_scratchpad> > 4:chain:RunnableParallel<agent_scratchpad>] [2ms] Exiting Chain run with output:
{
  "agent_scratchpad": []
}
[chain/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 2:chain:RunnableSequence > 3:chain:RunnableAssign<agent_scratchpad>] [3ms] Exiting Chain run with output:
{
  "input": "what is LangChain?",
  "intermediate_steps": [],
  "agent_scratchpad": []
}
[chain/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 2:chain:RunnableSequence > 6:prompt:ChatPromptTemplate] Entering Prompt run with input:
{
  "input": "what is LangChain?",
  "intermediate_steps": [],
  "agent_scratchpad": []
}
[chain/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 2:chain:RunnableSequence > 6:prompt:ChatPromptTemplate] [1ms] Exiting Prompt run with output:
{
  "lc": 1,
  "type": "constructor",
  "id": [
    "langchain",
    "prompts",
    "chat",
    "ChatPromptValue"
  ],
  "kwargs": {
    "messages": [
      {
        "lc": 1,
        "type": "constructor",
        "id": [
          "langchain",
          "schema",
          "messages",
          "SystemMessage"
        ],
        "kwargs": {
          "content": "You are a helpful assistant",
          "additional_kwargs": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "lc": 1,
        "type": "constructor",
        "id": [
          "langchain",
          "schema",
          "messages",
          "HumanMessage"
        ],
        "kwargs": {
          "content": "what is LangChain?",
          "additional_kwargs": {}
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
[llm/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 2:chain:RunnableSequence > 7:llm:ChatOpenAI] Entering LLM run with input:
{
  "prompts": [
    "System: You are a helpful assistant\nHuman: what is LangChain?"
  ]
}
[llm/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 2:chain:RunnableSequence > 7:llm:ChatOpenAI] [1.51s] Exiting LLM run with output:
{
  "generations": [
    [
      {
        "text": "",
        "generation_info": {
          "finish_reason": "tool_calls"
        },
        "type": "ChatGenerationChunk",
        "message": {
          "lc": 1,
          "type": "constructor",
          "id": [
            "langchain",
            "schema",
            "messages",
            "AIMessageChunk"
          ],
          "kwargs": {
            "content": "",
            "example": false,
            "additional_kwargs": {
              "tool_calls": [
                {
                  "index": 0,
                  "id": "call_PVNGpWSVfy921HhAQpaq54sY",
                  "function": {
                    "arguments": "{\"query\":\"LangChain\"}",
                    "name": "tavily_search_results_json"
                  },
                  "type": "function"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "llm_output": null,
  "run": null
}
[chain/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 2:chain:RunnableSequence > 8:parser:OpenAIToolsAgentOutputParser] Entering Parser run with input:
[inputs]
[chain/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 2:chain:RunnableSequence > 8:parser:OpenAIToolsAgentOutputParser] [1ms] Exiting Parser run with output:
{
  "output": [
    {
      "lc": 1,
      "type": "constructor",
      "id": [
        "langchain",
        "schema",
        "agent",
        "OpenAIToolAgentAction"
      ],
      "kwargs": {
        "tool": "tavily_search_results_json",
        "tool_input": {
          "query": "LangChain"
        },
        "log": "\nInvoking: `tavily_search_results_json` with `{'query': 'LangChain'}`\n\n\n",
        "message_log": [
          {
            "lc": 1,
            "type": "constructor",
            "id": [
              "langchain",
              "schema",
              "messages",
              "AIMessageChunk"
            ],
            "kwargs": {
              "content": "",
              "example": false,
              "additional_kwargs": {
                "tool_calls": [
                  {
                    "index": 0,
                    "id": "call_PVNGpWSVfy921HhAQpaq54sY",
                    "function": {
                      "arguments": "{\"query\":\"LangChain\"}",
                      "name": "tavily_search_results_json"
                    },
                    "type": "function"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "tool_call_id": "call_PVNGpWSVfy921HhAQpaq54sY"
      }
    }
  ]
}
[chain/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 2:chain:RunnableSequence] [1.53s] Exiting Chain run with output:
[outputs]
[tool/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 9:tool:tavily_search_results_json] Entering Tool run with input:
"{'query': 'LangChain'}"
[tool/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 9:tool:tavily_search_results_json] [1.06s] Exiting Tool run with output:
"[{'url': 'https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain', 'content': 'About\n⚡ Building applications with LLMs through composability ⚡\nResources\nLicense\nCode of conduct\nSecurity policy\nStars\nWatchers\nForks\nReleases\n291\nPackages\n0\nUsed by 39k\nContributors\n1,848\nLanguages\nFooter\nFooter navigation Latest commit\nGit stats\nFiles\nREADME.md\n️ LangChain\n⚡ Building applications with LLMs through composability ⚡\nLooking for the JS/TS library? ⚡ Building applications with LLMs through composability ⚡\nLicense\nlangchain-ai/langchain\nName already in use\nUse Git or checkout with SVN using the web URL.\n  Documentation\nPlease see here for full documentation, which includes:\n Contributing\nAs an open-source project in a rapidly developing field, we are extremely open to contributions, whether it be in the form of a new feature, improved infrastructure, or better documentation.\n What can you build with LangChain?\n❓ Retrieval augmented generation\n Analyzing structured data\n Chatbots\nAnd much more!'}]"
[chain/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 10:chain:RunnableSequence] Entering Chain run with input:
{
  "input": ""
}
[chain/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 10:chain:RunnableSequence > 11:chain:RunnableAssign<agent_scratchpad>] Entering Chain run with input:
{
  "input": ""
}
[chain/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 10:chain:RunnableSequence > 11:chain:RunnableAssign<agent_scratchpad> > 12:chain:RunnableParallel<agent_scratchpad>] Entering Chain run with input:
{
  "input": ""
}
[chain/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 10:chain:RunnableSequence > 11:chain:RunnableAssign<agent_scratchpad> > 12:chain:RunnableParallel<agent_scratchpad> > 13:chain:RunnableLambda] Entering Chain run with input:
{
  "input": ""
}
[chain/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 10:chain:RunnableSequence > 11:chain:RunnableAssign<agent_scratchpad> > 12:chain:RunnableParallel<agent_scratchpad> > 13:chain:RunnableLambda] [1ms] Exiting Chain run with output:
[outputs]
[chain/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 10:chain:RunnableSequence > 11:chain:RunnableAssign<agent_scratchpad> > 12:chain:RunnableParallel<agent_scratchpad>] [2ms] Exiting Chain run with output:
[outputs]
[chain/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 10:chain:RunnableSequence > 11:chain:RunnableAssign<agent_scratchpad>] [3ms] Exiting Chain run with output:
[outputs]
[chain/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 10:chain:RunnableSequence > 14:prompt:ChatPromptTemplate] Entering Prompt run with input:
[inputs]
[chain/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 10:chain:RunnableSequence > 14:prompt:ChatPromptTemplate] [1ms] Exiting Prompt run with output:
{
  "lc": 1,
  "type": "constructor",
  "id": [
    "langchain",
    "prompts",
    "chat",
    "ChatPromptValue"
  ],
  "kwargs": {
    "messages": [
      {
        "lc": 1,
        "type": "constructor",
        "id": [
          "langchain",
          "schema",
          "messages",
          "SystemMessage"
        ],
        "kwargs": {
          "content": "You are a helpful assistant",
          "additional_kwargs": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "lc": 1,
        "type": "constructor",
        "id": [
          "langchain",
          "schema",
          "messages",
          "HumanMessage"
        ],
        "kwargs": {
          "content": "what is LangChain?",
          "additional_kwargs": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "lc": 1,
        "type": "constructor",
        "id": [
          "langchain",
          "schema",
          "messages",
          "AIMessageChunk"
        ],
        "kwargs": {
          "content": "",
          "example": false,
          "additional_kwargs": {
            "tool_calls": [
              {
                "index": 0,
                "id": "call_PVNGpWSVfy921HhAQpaq54sY",
                "function": {
                  "arguments": "{\"query\":\"LangChain\"}",
                  "name": "tavily_search_results_json"
                },
                "type": "function"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "lc": 1,
        "type": "constructor",
        "id": [
          "langchain",
          "schema",
          "messages",
          "ToolMessage"
        ],
        "kwargs": {
          "content": "[{\"url\": \"https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain\", \"content\": \"About\\n⚡ Building applications with LLMs through composability ⚡\\nResources\\nLicense\\nCode of conduct\\nSecurity policy\\nStars\\nWatchers\\nForks\\nReleases\\n291\\nPackages\\n0\\nUsed by 39k\\nContributors\\n1,848\\nLanguages\\nFooter\\nFooter navigation Latest commit\\nGit stats\\nFiles\\nREADME.md\\n️ LangChain\\n⚡ Building applications with LLMs through composability ⚡\\nLooking for the JS/TS library? ⚡ Building applications with LLMs through composability ⚡\\nLicense\\nlangchain-ai/langchain\\nName already in use\\nUse Git or checkout with SVN using the web URL.\\n  Documentation\\nPlease see here for full documentation, which includes:\\n Contributing\\nAs an open-source project in a rapidly developing field, we are extremely open to contributions, whether it be in the form of a new feature, improved infrastructure, or better documentation.\\n What can you build with LangChain?\\n❓ Retrieval augmented generation\\n Analyzing structured data\\n Chatbots\\nAnd much more!\"}]",
          "tool_call_id": "call_PVNGpWSVfy921HhAQpaq54sY",
          "additional_kwargs": {
            "name": "tavily_search_results_json"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
[llm/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 10:chain:RunnableSequence > 15:llm:ChatOpenAI] Entering LLM run with input:
{
  "prompts": [
    "System: You are a helpful assistant\nHuman: what is LangChain?\nAI: \nTool: [{\"url\": \"https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain\", \"content\": \"About\\n⚡ Building applications with LLMs through composability ⚡\\nResources\\nLicense\\nCode of conduct\\nSecurity policy\\nStars\\nWatchers\\nForks\\nReleases\\n291\\nPackages\\n0\\nUsed by 39k\\nContributors\\n1,848\\nLanguages\\nFooter\\nFooter navigation Latest commit\\nGit stats\\nFiles\\nREADME.md\\n️ LangChain\\n⚡ Building applications with LLMs through composability ⚡\\nLooking for the JS/TS library? ⚡ Building applications with LLMs through composability ⚡\\nLicense\\nlangchain-ai/langchain\\nName already in use\\nUse Git or checkout with SVN using the web URL.\\n  Documentation\\nPlease see here for full documentation, which includes:\\n Contributing\\nAs an open-source project in a rapidly developing field, we are extremely open to contributions, whether it be in the form of a new feature, improved infrastructure, or better documentation.\\n What can you build with LangChain?\\n❓ Retrieval augmented generation\\n Analyzing structured data\\n Chatbots\\nAnd much more!\"}]"
  ]
}
[llm/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 10:chain:RunnableSequence > 15:llm:ChatOpenAI] [23.21s] Exiting LLM run with output:
{
  "generations": [
    [
      {
        "text": "LangChain is a platform for building applications with LLMs (Large Language Models) through composability. It allows for the creation of applications that utilize LLMs for tasks such as retrieval augmented generation, analyzing structured data, and building chatbots. LangChain is an open-source project with extensive documentation and is open to contributions from the community. You can find more information on LangChain at the following link: [LangChain GitHub Repository](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain)",
        "generation_info": {
          "finish_reason": "stop"
        },
        "type": "ChatGenerationChunk",
        "message": {
          "lc": 1,
          "type": "constructor",
          "id": [
            "langchain",
            "schema",
            "messages",
            "AIMessageChunk"
          ],
          "kwargs": {
            "content": "LangChain is a platform for building applications with LLMs (Large Language Models) through composability. It allows for the creation of applications that utilize LLMs for tasks such as retrieval augmented generation, analyzing structured data, and building chatbots. LangChain is an open-source project with extensive documentation and is open to contributions from the community. You can find more information on LangChain at the following link: [LangChain GitHub Repository](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain)",
            "example": false,
            "additional_kwargs": {}
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "llm_output": null,
  "run": null
}
[chain/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 10:chain:RunnableSequence > 16:parser:OpenAIToolsAgentOutputParser] Entering Parser run with input:
[inputs]
[chain/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 10:chain:RunnableSequence > 16:parser:OpenAIToolsAgentOutputParser] [1ms] Exiting Parser run with output:
{
  "lc": 1,
  "type": "constructor",
  "id": [
    "langchain",
    "schema",
    "agent",
    "AgentFinish"
  ],
  "kwargs": {
    "return_values": {
      "output": "LangChain is a platform for building applications with LLMs (Large Language Models) through composability. It allows for the creation of applications that utilize LLMs for tasks such as retrieval augmented generation, analyzing structured data, and building chatbots. LangChain is an open-source project with extensive documentation and is open to contributions from the community. You can find more information on LangChain at the following link: [LangChain GitHub Repository](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain)"
    },
    "log": "LangChain is a platform for building applications with LLMs (Large Language Models) through composability. It allows for the creation of applications that utilize LLMs for tasks such as retrieval augmented generation, analyzing structured data, and building chatbots. LangChain is an open-source project with extensive documentation and is open to contributions from the community. You can find more information on LangChain at the following link: [LangChain GitHub Repository](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain)"
  }
}
[chain/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 10:chain:RunnableSequence] [23.22s] Exiting Chain run with output:
[outputs]
[chain/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor] [26.22s] Exiting Chain run with output:
{
  "output": "LangChain is a platform for building applications with LLMs (Large Language Models) through composability. It allows for the creation of applications that utilize LLMs for tasks such as retrieval augmented generation, analyzing structured data, and building chatbots. LangChain is an open-source project with extensive documentation and is open to contributions from the community. You can find more information on LangChain at the following link: [LangChain GitHub Repository](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain)"
}
```

```
{'input': 'what is LangChain?',
 'output': 'LangChain is a platform for building applications with LLMs (Large Language Models) through composability. It allows for the creation of applications that utilize LLMs for tasks such as retrieval augmented generation, analyzing structured data, and building chatbots. LangChain is an open-source project with extensive documentation and is open to contributions from the community. You can find more information on LangChain at the following link: [LangChain GitHub Repository](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain)'}
```

The important parts are when it says "Entering LLM run with input".

```
[llm/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 2:chain:RunnableSequence > 7:llm:ChatOpenAI] Entering LLM run with input:
{
  "prompts": [
    "System: You are a helpful assistant\nHuman: what is LangChain?"
  ]
}
[llm/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 2:chain:RunnableSequence > 7:llm:ChatOpenAI] [1.51s] Exiting LLM run with output:
{
  "generations": [
    [
      {
        "text": "",
        "generation_info": {
          "finish_reason": "tool_calls"
        },
        "type": "ChatGenerationChunk",
        "message": {
          "lc": 1,
          "type": "constructor",
          "id": [
            "langchain",
            "schema",
            "messages",
            "AIMessageChunk"
          ],
          "kwargs": {
            "content": "",
            "example": false,
            "additional_kwargs": {
              "tool_calls": [
                {
                  "index": 0,
                  "id": "call_PVNGpWSVfy921HhAQpaq54sY",
                  "function": {
                    "arguments": "{\"query\":\"LangChain\"}",
                    "name": "tavily_search_results_json"
                  },
                  "type": "function"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "llm_output": null,
  "run": null
}
```

I only see "System:" and "Human:" in the input, yet a tool is being called in the output.

```
[llm/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 10:chain:RunnableSequence > 15:llm:ChatOpenAI] Entering LLM run with input:
{
  "prompts": [
    "System: You are a helpful assistant\nHuman: what is LangChain?\nAI: \nTool: [{\"url\": \"https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain\", \"content\": \"About\\n⚡ Building applications with LLMs through composability ⚡\\nResources\\nLicense\\nCode of conduct\\nSecurity policy\\nStars\\nWatchers\\nForks\\nReleases\\n291\\nPackages\\n0\\nUsed by 39k\\nContributors\\n1,848\\nLanguages\\nFooter\\nFooter navigation Latest commit\\nGit stats\\nFiles\\nREADME.md\\n️ LangChain\\n⚡ Building applications with LLMs through composability ⚡\\nLooking for the JS/TS library? ⚡ Building applications with LLMs through composability ⚡\\nLicense\\nlangchain-ai/langchain\\nName already in use\\nUse Git or checkout with SVN using the web URL.\\n  Documentation\\nPlease see here for full documentation, which includes:\\n Contributing\\nAs an open-source project in a rapidly developing field, we are extremely open to contributions, whether it be in the form of a new feature, improved infrastructure, or better documentation.\\n What can you build with LangChain?\\n❓ Retrieval augmented generation\\n Analyzing structured data\\n Chatbots\\nAnd much more!\"}]"
  ]
}
```

Also, since the openai api works with an array of messages, is it a guarantee that they use the terms "System:", "Human:", "AI:" and "Tool:"?